# VS2010 published project cannot be viewed in E

Tags: visual-studio-2010, publish

I just converted an app from VS2008 to VS2010. But when I try to view the site in IE I get the message "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage".  This same app worked perfectly when I published the VS2008 version to the same folder. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The app uses .NET 4.0 which requires an IIS 7 App Pool using .Net 4, not 2. When I created a .Net 4 App Pool and assigned it to the app website the problem was resolved.